# SELECT GRANT not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-grant

1. I created a view by joining 4 other views - in same DB
2. The 4 other views use tables from the same DB
3. The new view has different schema from the base view
4. the owner of all the schemas are same
5. Provided select grant on the new schema to users

Users are able to see old views other than the one I created. What am I missing

Comment: Without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to help debug. Can you share a little more about your problem, like what views are being used, how users are viewing them, etc?

Comment: The view is a simple inner join of 4 other  views and the users access it via sql server

Comment: SQL server is the dbms

Comment: Please share command you have used to grant access to users on view.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it is expected that **owner** of the tables (based on which views were created) GRANT access to users on view.

Comment: I had to drop and recreate the view and gray select again and it worked. query was fine , something was acting up... thanks for all your help